# Intersection of subgroup of finite index with infinite subgroup is infinite

Tags: group-theory

Let $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup of $G$ of finite index. Further, $F\subseteq G$ is an infinite subgroup of $G$.

Prove or disprove: $H\cap F$ is infinite.

Comment: $H \cap F$ has only finitely many cosets in $F$.

Comment: Why is my question considered to be off-topic?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Many consider questions asked without any hint of your own work, or without telling us how you came across it as being a bad question (see "missing context or other details"). It is, however, more or less a lottery as to which questions are put on hold and which aren't, which is a bit unfair. For that I am sorry.

Comment: @Arthur Okay, I see. I skipped those information on purpose because when I answer questions I don't like to read much. I simply want to know what has to be done and then do it (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for the indices $|F:H \cap F| \leq |G:H|$ (define a map $\phi: \{\text{cosets of } H \cap F \text{ in }  F\} \rightarrow \{\text {cosets of } H \text{ in } G\}$ by $\phi(g(H \cap F))=gH$ and show that $\phi$ is well-defined and injective.) Hence $F$ is infinite if and only if $H \cap F$ is infinite.

Comment: For injectivity we have to show that from $f_1H=f_2 H$ follows $f_1(F\cap H)=f_2(F\cap H)$. But I don't see how to show that.

Comment: Presumable $f_1,f_2 \in F$? This is really not difficult - try a bit more!

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, you're right. Let's assume we have $f_1=f_2h$ for an $h\in H$. We then have $f_1(F\cap H) = F\cap f_1 H = F\cap f_2 h H = F\cap f_2 H = f_2(F\cap H)$. What I first tried was $f_1(F\cap H) = f_2 h(F\cap H) = f_2 h F \cap f_2 H = ?$. Here I didn't know how to continue. But now I see how to continue: Replace the first $f_2$ by $f_1 h^{-1}$.

Comment: $f_1=f_2h$ implies $f_2^{-1}f_1=h \in F \cap H$. Hence$f_1(F \cap H)=f_2(F \cap H)$.